# Capture app console.log from an Android alpha/beta release?

Tags: android, cordova, in-app-purchase

Working on a Cordova app:

We are trying to find a way to capture JSON results of an in-app transaction. In debug mode, we have access to the console, but in-app billing is disabled; when we've pushed an alpha or beta release to our GDC, the in-app billing works but we do not have access to the console. We use variations of pop-up alerts but this is a flaky solution. The main annoyance stems from having to build & upload to GDC every time we want to test new things that have to do with in-app billing. Surely there is something we're missing.

Is there a way to read the console (or any output of that sort) from a built Android app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all plug your device to computer, from Android Studio, choose Tools > Android Device Monitor or click the Android Device Monitor icon. This will show your device and apps running on it. You can filter type of logs it is showing (because at moment device shows lot of logs).

But if you use command line then , in the SDK tools/ directory, enter the following command : 
`monitor`

 It will also open monitor tool. Here is [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monitor.html) to this tool.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick, thanks! Also, for reason that I am still unsure of, console.log() would only match the first argument. I think it has to do with the version of Cordova used for this app (3.5.0-0.2.7) and some missing plugins. We just ended up using multiple console.log()